Router Bit Profile Identification
I've attached a photo. I'd like to replicate this profile.
As you can see, the profile was generated by an insert. But I wondered if anyone knew of a similar router bit profile?
180 bullnose, plunge-like bit. Kind of inverted flute. I've had a look online, but couldn't anything.
Any help would be appreciated.


Google ‘router beading bit’, (assuming you’re doing adjacent panels).

"I'd like to replicate this profile." Exactly as in the photo, and same application? If so, any standard production process that would generate the beading strip could be used, then you simply glue the strip into a milled, planed or chiselled groove.

If you want to make that profile as it in a flat board, it will be almost impossible.  a beading bit can make that on a piece of wood
but not in the middle of a board, since there is no way for the router holding the bit to get close enough to for that to happen.  making it out of 2 pieces like your example a beading bit is exactly what you need.
However if you would like to do a similar profile in the middle of board, you can use a Hollow Moulding plane.  Molding planes have many different profiles and 'partial profiles' and are what was used long before the power router was invented.
and if you can't find a hollow with the right profile, you can probably find a beading plane that you can use with 2 passes instead.

Even a hastily filed scratch stock with a guide would work on a flat panel (in limited volumes).

@AloysiusDefenestrate, yes but scratch stocks are generally for edge use. And they are generally used along the grain; here it would need to work both cross-grain and along the grain. None of this is insurmountable, but much more detail would be need to be provided to help the OP if they wanted to try this out in place on a door constructed as in the photo.

Agreed, @Graphus. I guess my issue is the lack of clarity in the question makes me unwilling to guess my way down a particular rabbit hole of a solution. Perhaps the OP could help.

@AloysiusDefenestrate, I've asked for a clarification from the OP, well see how that goes........
